# Python3, Robot Framework: Prevent CMD opening when calling .robot file from .py file

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I created automation using Python3 and robot framework.

I used Python (PyQt5) to create GUI for the user.
When user has filled all the options in GUI that are needed, robot framework file is called:

```
from subprocess import call
```

`call([pythonExeFilePath, '-m', 'robot', robotFilePath])`

Now the problem with this is that when I create .exe file (with pyinstaller) out of that python file, which calls .robot file, when I launch my .py file with that desktop icon I created with pyinstaller, it launches CMD when .robot part comes.

I used `pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py`  to create .exe file, this .py file won't open cmd when I launch it, but as soon as it gets to part where it calls .robot file, it opens up the CMD.

How could I prevent CMD to open when .robot file is called?

Comment: Have you tried including [creationflag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW) ``CREATE_NO_WINDOW`` to your ``subprocess.call``? I've not dealt with this exact issue before so I'm uncertain how Robot will behave in this instance but this creation flag is supposed to prevent any new windows from opening.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your respond @Morkkis ! I'm not entirely sure how to include that into my
call([pythonExeFilePath, '-m', 'robot', robotFilePath]) , so can you help out a little. I can only test it by always creating a new desktop application, so guessing is a little hard... he

Comment: You'll need to add first it to import like ``from subprocess import call, CREATE_NO_WINDOW`` and then it should work just as an input argument like ``call([pythonExeFilePath, '-m', 'robot', robotFilePath], creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)``.